# Blogger To WordPress migration issue

Tags: blogger, wordpress, migration

After I migrated from Blogger to WordPress, I imported Blogger posts to WordPress, but `<br />` line break not working in WordPress and my all content lines has joined in one line.

How can I solve it?

Screenshot before migration:

[image]
[image]

after migration:

[image]